# Several Operations Within a Matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

i'd like someone with knowledge on matlab to help me sort this out, the plan is to write a script as follow [image]

it starts reading numbers on *column 2* and  check in *column 3* one if they are repeated:
The Condition is, if a number in *column 2* is repeated **more than one time** in *column 3*, the corresponding values in *column 4* will **be summed up**, if a number from *column 2* **is not repeated or only repeated one time** in *column 3*, its corresponding value in *column 4* will be left as it is. The obtained values would be generated in a vector. the letters were put there just for explanation here is an example to try with

```
data=[0   1    0     0
      1   2    1    200
      2   3    1    300
      3   4    1    400
      4   5    2    500
      5   6    3    600
      6   7    4    700
      7   8    5    800
      8   9    5    900
      9   10   5    1000
      10  11   6    1100
      11  12   7    1200
      12  13   7    1300];

v=[(200+300+400) 200 300 400 (800+900+1000)  600 (1200+1300)  800 900 1000 1100 1200 1300]
```

waiting on any ideas.Thank you programmers !

Comment: What would the output be, for this `data` example?

Comment: Could you please provide the code that you've tried and detail some of the issues that you are having with it?

Comment: i just can't figure how to translate the given condition into a matlab code, i have added a the desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we break down your problem, we can figure out one way to go about getting your answer.

Essentially, for each value in column 2 (`data(:,2)`), we create a logical matrix that finds all values in column 3 (`data(:,2)`) that match it:

```
toinclude = data(:,3) == data(k,2)
```

Now we need to see how many matches there are

```
matches = sum(toinclude)
```

If there is `<2` matches then we simply use the value otherwise we sum all the values in column 4

```
if matches < 2
    value = data(k,4)
else
    value = sum(data(toinclude, 4));
end
```

And we want to do this for all elements in column 2.

All of this could be written as a `for` loop, but there is likely a one-line solution.

```
output = zeros(size(data, 1), 1);

for k = 1:size(data,1)
    toinclude = data(:,3) == data(k, 2);

    if sum(toinclude) < 2
        output(k) = data(k, 4);
    else
        output(k) = sum(data(toinclude, 4));
    end
end
```

For the data you provided this yields the following result

```
     900
     200
     300
     400
    2700
     600
    2500
     800
     900
    1000
    1100
    1200
    1300
```

Comment: hey Jonathan S thanx for the quick answer, the detailed you mentioned is already provided (is not repeated or only repeated one time) so if the value in column 2 doesnt exist in column 3 , the value will be treated the same as repeated one time in column3. i have tried the code you posted doesn't match with the desired output , but thanx anyway

Comment: @gabby113 I just edited my answer based on your clarification. Please check and let me know how it goes.

Comment: does k has an initial value? i' am getting this error ??? Undefined function or variable 'k'.

Comment: `k` is the index. Look at the full example near the end that starts with `output = ...`